# How do I take a snapshot with a laptop on 1.5.2 in Minecraft? F2 makes it dimmer

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'd really like it if someone might be able to help me. I need an answer so that I can make a picture for another post.

Comment: Your laptop probably has a *fn* button you can press to modify your  function keys.  F2 on my laptop is a dimmer switch too.  Try pressing it while holding *fn*.

Answer (score 4):

Without knowing your exact laptop keyboard layout (may differ slightly between brands/models), what you probably need to do is hit the <kbd>*fn*</kbd> key on your keyboard. This should toggle the the F keys between their usual function and and their special additional functions (screen settings, volume, etc).

If the <kbd>*fn*</kbd> doesn't exist on your keyboard, it may have been labeled something different. My keyboard has <kbd>ⒻMode</kbd>, for example.

Comment: Thank you. Now I can take snapshots and cough it onto somebody